# Android Studio button overlap error (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a login screen with RelativeLayout, and when I run the emulator as shown in the picture, the buttons look overlapping. Should I change the layout? How do I solve this?
Please help me. I'd appreciate your help.

The corresponding login xml source code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_loginView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:text="로그인"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EtPwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="391dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="비밀번호를 입력해주세요"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="315dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/EmView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="319dp"
    android:text="이메일"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="495dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="이메일을 입력해주세요"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="229dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pwView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="402dp"
    android:text="비밀번호"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="323dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Login"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="294dp"
    android:background="@color/Gray"
    android:text="로그인"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="493dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Register"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="592dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="132dp"
    android:text="회원가입 하기"
    android:textColor="#8A8A8A"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="286dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="398dp" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqxhT.png)

I attached the emulator execution photo as above.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below contents to understand the layout designing using `RelativeLayout`.

1. The attributes with `tools:` namespace will not be rendered on the emulator or device. They are only for preview screen. So, when you use `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"` it only affects the view position on preview screen and gets ignored on emulator or physical device. Avoid using `tools:` namespace attributes for defining position of the views.
2. To arrange views relative to the parent, we have following attributes for `RelativeLayout`.

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

As the names clearly suggest, they align your view w.r.t to the parent at Start, Top, End or Bottom respectively. Next attributes are for arranging the view in center w.r.t the parent horizontally, vertically or both, respectively.

3. To arrange a view relative to other view, use following attributes with the `id` of the view you want them relative to.

```
android:layout_below="@id/view"
android:layout_above="@id/view"
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/view"
android:layout_alignStart="@id/view"
```

The first two are for aligning vertically and next two are for aligning horizontally. The names are self-explanatory.

4. To give spacing you can use margins. You can define them for each direction or all at once.

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

**Design Process** : The basic process includes designing from top-left direction. Arrange a view relative to parent and then arrange the other views relative to the previous view forming a chain. You can additionally, arrange relative to parent if required like putting a view at bottom.

This is final xml layout using the above information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_loginView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:text="로그인"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="130dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EmView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_loginView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="이메일"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/EmView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="이메일을 입력해주세요"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pwView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/EtEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="비밀번호"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EtPwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pwView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="비밀번호를 입력해주세요"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Login"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/Btn_Register"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:text="로그인"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Register"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="회원가입 하기"
        android:textColor="#8A8A8A"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample Output:
[image: Sample Output]

Below are the things that were done wrong in your code.

1. Using `tools:` namespace to define absolute position. I already mentioned above what's the use to this namespace. If you are manually dragging the view to position, it might be causing this so don't manually position views, instead use code.
2. Using improper margin `android:layout_marginTop="592dp"`, you aligned the register button to the top of your parent and then you are moving it below using margin. Instead align it to parent bottom and using margin to define spacing between the bottom of your screen.
3. Use relative attributes as mentioned above to align views, instead of finding a combination of margin.

*Hope this helps!! Keep building apps! All the best for your journey!*

Comment: You're the one who answered the last question, too!
Thank you very much for your detailed reply. Thank you so much. I solved it again this time.
I wish you all the best in your future!